Possible zombie/werewolf movie from the 80s/90s. Group of people stuck in a castle/mansion are hunted by savage creatures
I've been looking for an old movie I watched, but haven't had any luck so far. Here are the details I remember about it.

I'm pretty sure I watched this movie between 1996 and 2003.
The movie looked a bit older than that though, I'd say it was released at least between mid 80s and early 90s.
I watched it dubbed in Portuguese, so I can't confirm it's American. But the only character name I remember sounds like it (more on that later).
There are specifically 3 characters I remember from this movie. Ages seem to range between 20 and 30 years old:

A guy who seems to be the main character. He had blackish hair and I think it was close to shoulder length.
A black (maybe brown?) haired girl who seemed to be the character's girlfriend. He called out to her a lot, so I believe she was at least very important to him. Pretty sure her name was Mary Lou (can't confirm the spelling of it though). 
A blonde girl who seems to be friends with the other two. Her hair was short and in my mind seems similar to Marilyn Monroe's.


Now, to the relevant plot details and scenes I remember (which, sadly, are only a few):

The group is definitely being chased by a kind of creature, similar to a zombie or werewolf (the latter seems more accurate). 
They are inside a kind of castle, or a pretty old mansion, at least during the scenes I remember.
The most memorable scene is when the blonde girl, using a white dress, goes outside the castle door (I believe it was a very big, double door) into the backyard. I remember quite clearly that the scenery was very desert-like, with a lot of dirt (almost looked like sand) and a few dead trees scattered around. And there was a lot of those werewolf-like creatures just waiting for her. I don't remember if she was using herself as bait or just wanted to kill herself, but I'm pretty sure she was attacked and killed by them during that scene. I know that when I watched I felt it was a suicidal move either way.
The other scene is not so clear in my mind, but it took place shortly after the one above. The other girl (Mary Lou) was apparently running around the castle as the creature was chasing her inside. All I remember was the main guy screaming "Mary Lou!", he seemed to be looking for her. I don't remember the details, but it seems he found her dead later. Also, my memory has the feeling that he wasn't exactly a good character, so he might have been sided with the creatures (if they were werewolves it's possible that he was even one of them).

P.S.: When searching, I thought that the movie was Howling V: The Rebirth (it has a Mary Lou and similar characters and setting), but I watched on YouTube and none of the scenes clicked my mind. Also, the movie I remember seemed to have a brighter color (meaning it could be a little more recent).
That's about all I remember about this. Hope it rings a bell to someone here. I'll update if I remember any more details. 
Thanks a lot

Did you check the other "howling" movies? May be Howling VI: The Freaks

I was going to suggest other Howling movies -- seems like it would be a good fit. Not a whole lot of werewolf movies out that would fit those scenes..

Thanks for the suggestion, @madmada and Tim. I also checked the sequel and it wasn't it either. About the previous Howling movies, it seems that Mary Lou didn't even appear so I haven't checked them much thoroughly.
